# count row by time period in R with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

```
library(data.table)

dt <- fread(" ID  DATE    
              A1 20170220
              A1 20170308
              A1 20170311
              A1 20170410
              A1 20170411
              A1 20170413
              A1 20170415
              A1 20170416
              A1 20170420
              A1 20170430
              A2 20170120
              A2 20170121
              A2 20170123
              A2 20170125
              A2 20170202 ")
```

and trying to count N like this :

```
 ID  DATE     count30day(count rows until after 30day)
 A1 20170220      3 (count row until 20170322)
 A1 20170308      2 (count row until 20170407)
 A1 20170311      2 (count row until 20170410)
 A1 20170410      7 (count row until 20170510)
 A1 20170411      6 (count row until 20170511)
 A1 20170413      5 (count row until 20170513)
 A1 20170415      4 (count row until 20170514)
 A1 20170416      3 (count row until 20170516)
 A1 20170420      2 (count row until 20170520)
 A1 20170430      1 (count row until 20170530)
 A2 20170120      5 (count row until 20170220)
 A2 20170121      4 (count row until 20170220)
 A2 20170123      3 (count row until 20170220) 
 A2 20170125      2 (count row until 20170220)
 A2 20170202      1 (count row until 20170220)
```

I tried this

```
dt[,N:=sapply(DATE, function(x) nrow(dt[x<=DATE&DATE < (x + months(1))]))]
```

It was work but last 5 value is wrong.
It is gotta be 54321 but result was 55432.

and actuall data that I handling is about 2500000 rows so it takes so long time

is anyway that can reduce time and fix last value problem?

Comment: Please, make a reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using non-equi self-join:

```
dt[, N := 
    dt[.(ID=ID, stt=DATE, end=DATE+30), on=.(ID, DATE>=stt, DATE<=end), .N, by=.EACHI]$N
]
```

output:

```
    ID       DATE N
 1: A1 2017-02-20 3
 2: A1 2017-03-08 2
 3: A1 2017-03-11 2
 4: A1 2017-04-10 7
 5: A1 2017-04-11 6
 6: A1 2017-04-13 5
 7: A1 2017-04-15 4
 8: A1 2017-04-16 3
 9: A1 2017-04-20 2
10: A1 2017-04-30 1
11: A2 2017-01-20 5
12: A2 2017-01-21 4
13: A2 2017-01-23 3
14: A2 2017-01-25 2
15: A2 2017-02-02 1
```

data:

```
library(data.table)    
dt <- fread(" ID  DATE    
              A1 20170220
              A1 20170308
              A1 20170311
              A1 20170410
              A1 20170411
              A1 20170413
              A1 20170415
              A1 20170416
              A1 20170420
              A1 20170430
              A2 20170120
              A2 20170121
              A2 20170123
              A2 20170125
              A2 20170202 ")
dt[, DATE := as.Date(as.character(DATE), "%Y%m%d")]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another data.table solution

```
#set strings to actual dates
dt[, DATE := lubridate::ymd( DATE ) ]
#set key for the join
setkey(dt, DATE)
#join, suspend output until we calculated the number of 'hits' per row (.EACHI)
dt[dt, N := {
  val = dt[ ID == i.ID & DATE %between% c( i.DATE, i.DATE + 30 ) ];
  list( nrow( val ) )
}, by = .EACHI]
```

**output**

```
#     ID       DATE N
#  1: A2 2017-01-20 5
#  2: A2 2017-01-21 4
#  3: A2 2017-01-23 3
#  4: A2 2017-01-25 2
#  5: A2 2017-02-02 1
#  6: A1 2017-02-20 3
#  7: A1 2017-03-08 2
#  8: A1 2017-03-11 2
#  9: A1 2017-04-10 7
# 10: A1 2017-04-11 6
# 11: A1 2017-04-13 5
# 12: A1 2017-04-15 4
# 13: A1 2017-04-16 3
# 14: A1 2017-04-20 2
# 15: A1 2017-04-30 1
```

**benchmarks**

```
# Unit: milliseconds
#              expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# data.table_wimpel 10.51381 10.73975 11.41636 11.32511 11.89540 13.31526    10
# data.table_ronak  25.42636 25.56223 27.39190 26.46919 29.55910 32.10598    10
# tidyverse_ronak   28.09526 28.73364 30.30307 28.98098 29.45968 38.50784    10

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  data.table_wimpel = {
    dt = copy(DT)
    dt[, DATE := lubridate::ymd( DATE ) ]
    setkey(dt, DATE)
    dt[dt, N := {
      val = dt[ ID == i.ID & DATE %between% c( i.DATE, i.DATE + 30 ) ];
      list( nrow( val ) )
    }, by = .EACHI ] },
  data.table_ronak = {
    dt = copy(DT)
    dt$DATE <- ymd(dt$DATE) #Convert to date
    dt$row <- 1:nrow(dt)    #Add row number
    dt[ , N:= mapply(function(x, y) 
      sum(x <= DATE & DATE < (x + months(1)) & y <= row), DATE, row)]    
  },
  tidyverse_ronak = {
    dt = copy(DT)
    dt %>%
      mutate(DATE = ymd(DATE),
             row = row_number(),
             N = map2_dbl(DATE, row, 
                          ~ sum(.x <= DATE & DATE < (.x + months(1)) & .y <= row))) %>%
      select(-row)
  },
  times = 10 )
```

Comment: As you can see in the benchmarks, this answer is (probably) faster on your large dataset than the (100% working) solution from @RonakShah .I'm curious if it's working for you, since I'm always struggling with these kind of self-joins..

Answer (score 1):

I think we need to keep an additional check on the current row number.

Using data.table:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

dt[, DATE := ymd(DATE) # convert 'DATE' to Date format by reference
  ][, row := .I        # Add row number using inbuilt var '.I' by reference
   ][ , N := mapply(function(x, y) 
               sum(x <= DATE & DATE < (x + months(1)) & y <= row), DATE, row)]
```

OR using `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
dt %>%
  mutate(DATE = ymd(DATE),
         row = row_number(),
         N = map2_dbl(DATE, row, 
             ~ sum(.x <= DATE & DATE < (.x + months(1)) & .y <= row))) %>%
  select(-row)


#   ID       DATE N
#1  A1 2017-02-20 3
#2  A1 2017-03-08 2
#3  A1 2017-03-11 2
#4  A1 2017-04-10 7
#5  A1 2017-04-11 6
#6  A1 2017-04-13 5
#7  A1 2017-04-15 4
#8  A1 2017-04-16 3
#9  A1 2017-04-20 2
#10 A1 2017-04-30 1
#11 A2 2017-01-20 5
#12 A2 2017-01-21 4
#13 A2 2017-01-23 3
#14 A2 2017-01-25 2
#15 A2 2017-02-02 1
```